# Мониторинг значения переменной на JS или jQuery

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Состояние элемента, событие отслеживается на jQuery через live или on. А как аналогично можно отследить именно значение переменной, которое "висит в памяти" (через firebug явно видно, что данная переменная имеет постоянно какое-либо значение)?

Answer (score 2):

Стандартных функций слежения нет, можно воспользоваться [watch.js](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS).